# getchar() keeps reading a '\n'. What is going on?

Tags: c, arrays, stdin, prompt, getchar

I have a small program I'm writing to practice programming in C.

I want it to use the getchar(); function to get input from the user.
I use the following function to prompt for user input, then loop using getchar() to store input in an array:

The function is passed a pointer referencing a struct's member.

```
getInput(p->firstName); //The function is passed an argument like this one




void getInput(char * array)
{
    int c;

    while((c=getchar()) != '\n')
        *array++ = c;
    *array = '\0'; //Null terminate
}
```

This function is called multiple times, as it is a part of a function that creates a structure, and populates it's array members.

However when the program executes, The first two calls to it work fine, but any subsequent calls to this function will cause every-other call to getchar() to not wait for keyboard input.

After some debugging I traced the bug to be that getchar(); was for some reason reading in the '\n' character instead of waiting for input, the while loop test fails, and the function returns essentially an empty string.

I have done some research and keep finding to use

```
while(getchar() != '\n');
```

at the end of the function in order to properly flush stdin, however, this produces undesirable results, as the program will prompt again for more input after I type ENTER. Pressing ENTER again continues the program, but every-other subsequent calls continue to read in this mysterious '\n' character right off the bat, causing the test to fail, and resulting in empty strings whenever it comes time to print the contents of the the structure.

Could anyone explain to me what is going on here? Why does getchar() keep fetching a '\n' even though I supposedly cleared the input buffer? I have tried just placing a getchar(); statement at the beginning and end of the function, tried 'do while' loops, and taken other jabs at it, but I can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: You should always check for EOF too: `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')` (or you can test for newline first and EOF second).  Whether that's actually the source of your trouble is debatable at best.

Comment: What _other_ functions are you reading input with? Please post a complete program that shows your problem.

Comment: I have tried the above line of code and it still yields the same undesirable results, though I do ultimately plan to design the program accordingly. Baby steps!

Comment: Wait a minute... Random832... I think you just solved my issue... I have a scanf() function right after a call to my getInput! I will check immediately!

Comment: Yes! Thank you @Random832 for asking the right questions! I placed a getchar while loop after a scanf function that I had and it worked! Bug Squashed!

Comment: @AlejandroZapien Glad I could help - I strongly suspected there was a scanf involved.  The semantics of the scanf function have other "gotchas" too, I'd recommend switching to strictly reading lines into a line buffer and doing any further parsing if necessary with sscanf instead.

Comment: You have nothing here preventing a buffer overrun. What happens if someone provides a gigabyte file with no newlines to your program?

Comment: @AlejandroZapien can you show strucuture `p`?

Comment: Post your own answer, accept it, to close this post.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have written has several drawbacks. I'll try to explain them as it is unclear where your code is failing (probably outside the function you posted)

- First of all, you don't check for `EOF` in `getchar()` result value.  `getchar(3)` doesn't return a `char` precisely to allow to return al possible `char` values plus an extra one, `EOF`, to mark the end of file (this can be generated from a terminal by input of `Ctrl-D` in unix, or `Ctrl-Z` on windows machines)  That case must be explicitly contempled in your code, as you'll convert the result to a `char` and will lose the extra information you received from the function.  Read `getchar(3)` man page to solve this issue.
- Second, you don't check for input of enough characters to fill all the array and overflow it.  To the function you pass only a pointer to the beginning of the array, but nothing indicates how far it extends, so you can be overfilling past the end of its bounds, just overwritting memory that was not reserved for input purposes.  This normally results in something called U.B. in the literature (**U**ndefined **B**ehaviour) and is something you must care of.  This can be solved by passing a counter of valid positions to fill in the array and decrementing it for each valid position filled.  And not allowing more input once the buffer has filled up.

On other side, you have a standar function that does exactly that, `fgets(3)` just reads one string array from an input file, and stores it on the pointer (and size) you pass to it:

```
char *fgets(char *buffer, size_t buffer_size, FILE *file_descriptor);
```

You can use it as in:

```
char buffer[80], *line;
...
while (line = fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)) {
    /* process one full line of input, with the final \n included */
    ....
}

/* on EOF, fgets(3) returns NULL, so we shall be here after reading the
 * full input file */
```